# Make the last parameters of a function conditional to the definition

Tags: c, gcc

I have a function that I'd want to have less parameters in some cases.

I did this which doesn't quite work:

```
int uid_fill_unique_ids(struct ha_sensor *wdt,
            struct ha_sensor *temp,
            struct ha_sensor *hum,
            struct ha_sensor *co2,
#ifdef CONFIG_APP_ENABLE_SPS30
            struct ha_sensor *pm1_sensor,
            struct ha_sensor *pm25_sensor,
            struct ha_sensor *pm10_sensor,
#endif
            )
{
}
```

It seems to be due to the trailing comma of the last function parameter.

Are trailing commas in function parameter lists illegal in C?

Anyway, is there a work around for this?

Comment: Write complete function declarations for each option. It will make it more readable too.

Comment: If the first parameter is always included, you could move all the commas to the next line: `int uid_fill_unique_ids(struct ha_sensor *wdt` `, struct ha_sensor *temp` `, struct ha_sensor *hum` `, struct ha_sensor *co2` `#ifdef CONFIG_APP_ENABLE_SPS30` `, struct ha_sensor *pm1_sensor` `, struct ha_sensor *pm25_sensor` `struct ha_sensor *pm10_sensor` `#endif` `)`.

Comment: @Ian Abbott Comments aren't for answers, especially answers posted 10 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trailing commas are indeed illegal here.

```c
int uid_fill_unique_ids(struct ha_sensor *wdt,
            struct ha_sensor *temp,
            struct ha_sensor *hum,
            struct ha_sensor *co2
#ifdef CONFIG_APP_ENABLE_SPS30
            , struct ha_sensor *pm1_sensor
            , struct ha_sensor *pm25_sensor
            , struct ha_sensor *pm10_sensor
#endif
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int uid_fill_unique_ids(struct ha_sensor *wdt,
            struct ha_sensor *temp,
            struct ha_sensor *hum,
            struct ha_sensor *co2
#ifdef CONFIG_APP_ENABLE_SPS30
            , // Added comma, format how you think is best
            struct ha_sensor *pm1_sensor,
            struct ha_sensor *pm25_sensor,
            struct ha_sensor *pm10_sensor // Removed comma
#endif
            )
{
}
```

Trailing commas in function arguments are indeed illegal in C

Answer (score 0):

This is unconventional, but... If you have your heart set on doing this, just rearrange things a little bit:

```
typedef struct ha_sensor Ha_s;
int uid_fill_unique_ids(
#ifdef CONFIG_APP_ENABLE_SPS30
    Ha_s *pm1_sensor,
    Ha_s *pm25_sensor,
    Ha_s *pm10_sensor,
#endif
    Ha_s *wdt,
    Ha_s *temp,
    Ha_s *hum,
    Ha_s *co2
    )
{
    // code
}
```

would seem to be less of a challenge. Avoid the "trailing comma" problem completely. Avoid having to wrestle with "where do I put the comma?" in all the code that calls this function.

Either there are 7 parameters (the first 3 inside an `#ifdef`) using 6 commas or there are 4 parameters using 3 commas.